# Ubuntu 12.04 APT Proxy?

Tags: 12.04, apt, proxy

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a password-protected proxy network. My web browser is configured and works, but I cannot install packages from `apt` or similar. Is there a way to configure `apt` to use my proxy? Is there a way to configure my entire system to use my proxy?

Comment: See [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set proxy in System Settings --> Network --> Network Proxy.

If it still not OK for apt, you can use several methods, I personally use method adding
the following lines to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
Acquire::https::proxy "http://username:password@proxyserver:port/";
```

Save and reboot